# Assign content to a specific th-element

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, bootstrap-4

Is there a way for passing content as a td-element to a specific th-element?
I have a dynamic table and need to assign the content under the right table header.

I have included pagination for the rows of the table. All the td-are assigned to "Ref."(see the picture attached). But I need to assign {{score}} under "Score", and the black part und er "title"

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead id="header">
        <tr id="tableHead">
            <th>Ref.</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="width: 100%">
        {% for i in range (0,numofresults) %}
        <tr id="cardmb3n{{i}}">
            <td id="ref{{i}}"> </td>
            <td id="score{{i}}"> </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <a id="header{{i}}" href="" </a> 
                    <br>
                    <a id="hyperlink{{i}}" href="" target=_blank </a> 
                </div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
    {% endfor %}                            
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're looking for this.

I assumed that you are having the data in JSON format which is dynamic.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "score": 86,
    "ref": "desc 021",
    "title": "021"
  },
  {
    "score": 72,
    "title": "022",
    "ref": "desc 022"
  }
];


function addTable() {

  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myTable");
  myTableDiv.innerHTML = "";

  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border = '1';

  var tableHeader = document.createElement('THEAD');
  table.appendChild(tableHeader);

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var n = data.length;
  var m = 0;
  var thKeys;
  if (n > 0) {
    thKeys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    m = thKeys.length;
  }

  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';
    td.innerText = thKeys[j];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.width = '75';
      td.innerText = data[i][thKeys[j]];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="addTable()">add table</button>

<div id="myTable"></div>
```

If you give me the exact data I will make the changes for it.

Comment: Yes, the data is in JSON. The number of cloumns is not the Problem, it is a fix number of 3. Yet, because of the pagination, the td- elments are all assigned to the "Ref." Element. I attached a screenshot of my Table.

Comment: I've made few changes. try now.